# Migration paths

Tags: discussion, migration

I think this is as good a place as any to start keeping a meta record of what our migration paths should be once we reach that stage of our site.

Currently, in beta, we cannot have any more paths set up but keeping a record of our ideas is never a bad thing.

Currently we have suggested of

- [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)
- [**Skeptics**](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)
- [**Physics**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [**Audio-Video Production**](https://video.stackexchange.com/)
- [**Music Fans**](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/)

Please add any other SE site you think should be a migration path and why.

Comment: Might I remind everyone **not to migrate crap**? So if a question is off-topic here, its fine if it doesn't get a new home elsewhere if you think its a poor question to begin with.

Comment: Aye, point taken.

Answer (score 4):

literature.stackexchange.com would be another useful one in due course.

Answer (score 2):

Due to [**this meta question**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/are-questions-about-cinematography-on-topic), I move to include [**AVP**](http://avp.stackexchange.com) on this list.

Answer (score 0):

my list:

- sci-fi
- literature
- physics (for those questions about how it's possible for something to happen)

Answer (score -1):

Skeptics.StackExchange.com was suggested in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/749/bulletproof-glass-breaking-scene-in-the-adventures-of-tintin) because the likeliness of a physical phenomenon was questioned. I can imagine this will occur more often, given special effects, stunts and many more ways reality can be "helped" in movies.

Comment: actually that particular quesiton is more on-topic for physics than skeptics.

Comment: Skeptics does require you to back up your questions, given how movies are mostly made up by definition, I don't think this would be really appropriate

Comment: For the record: the linked question was moved to physics.

Answer (score -2):

Since identification questions turned off-topic, I would suggest to migrate to [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) questions related to music, soundtrack identification.

Other trivia questions off-topic here, but related to Music knowledge are also allowed there.