# Are questions about cinematography on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Are questions germaine to the idea of cinematography on-topic?

More specifically, questions that relate to developing or creating movies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as in the [**FAQ**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) it states that:

> Questions about a Movie/TV show's production.

Are listed as **On-Topic**, I would not have a problem with those types of questions being here.

However, really specific questions are better left for the [**Audio-Video Production**](https://video.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site (within the guidelines of [**their own FAQ**](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq), of course).

Comment: Ah there's a audio-video production SE.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would think it would be on topic - it would be interesting to see people's views.

I am not sure however how many expert opinions you would have here, but it might be worth a try.